# Via Node Red, save MQTT message as multiple values to sql

Tags: mqtt, node-red

I am doing a school project where we get temperature data from two sides of a rack, with two BME280 sensors hooked up to a ESP32. The ESP32 then via MQTT publish to a topic. A raspberry pi then subscribe to a wildcard topic and saves it into a sqlite db. This should be done via Node-red.

Our initial thought was to make sqlite db with tables as:
"Rack#, location1, location2,temperature"

Then the ESP32 reads from BME280 in the front of the rack and publish it to a topic called "measurements/1/top/front"
with the payload as the tempereature.
So i want to take the topic and break into variables that i can put into the sql.

So i want a output as this:

Topic = measurements/1/top/front

payload = 20

=

SQL table

| Rack# | Location1 | Location2 | Temperature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | top | front | 20 |

I am new to it all and open for ideas

Comment: What you propose looks workable; I'm not really clear what your question/issue is?

Comment: Just to follow up on what @Brits said. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, you need to ask a specific question we can give a definitive answer to. Without that your question will just get closed. Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) about questions